# How to configure QODBC driver to work with your QuickBooks?

Tags: mysql, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am very new to the QuickBooks/ODBC world.

I am running on QuickBooks Enterprise Version 12.0

I am trying to install QODBC so I can query data out of my QuickBooks file (.qbw). After download, and install a trail version of QODBC from [here](http://www.qodbc.com/qodbcDownload.htm), I launched QuickBooks at the same time. Then, I went to

> File > Utilities > Configure ODBC

Then I got to this window

[image]

When I click on `Test Connection to QuickBooks` I keep getting this

[image]

Did I forget any steps ? 
Did I do anything that I'm not suppose to ?

Do I need to install the QBSDK ?

Do I have to logged in as Admin to grant the permission to QODBC driver ?

Can someone help me resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to install the QBSDK ?

No - I don't think so.

> Do I have to logged in as Admin to grant the permission to QODBC driver ?

**YES** - You suppose to logged in as administrator in order to grant the access for the QODBC for some security reasons.

Can someone help me resolve this ?

- Ask someone who have the admin right to your company QuickBooks to sign in
- Run the QODBC driver, your test connection to be working now.
- Follow the rest of the steps here :http://www.qodbc.com/qodbcconnect.htm

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with Tiffany Soun,

with addition to information shared by Tiffany Soun, I would like to share few links.

[Connecting QODBC Driver to QuickBooks for the First Time -Video](http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2512)

&

[TroubleShooting: Begin Session Failed. Error = 8004041d, 80040418, 8004041a, 80040430](http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2147/59/troubleshooting-begin-session-failed-error--8004041d-80040418-8004041a-80040430)

Answer (score 0):

For the next person reading this post:  after configuring your connection to an OPEN company file logged in as Admin.  Just press Apply or Save.  Then using the QODBC-provided VBDemo.exe program, open the connection using that DSN name you just configured.  QuickBooks will display the authorization for QODBC to connect.